# Can't receive packets in Aircrack-ng

Tags: aircrack-ng

So when I use: sudo airodump-ng -c 6 --bssid #### -w wepdump -i mon0

I don't see any packets generating as it runs, BSSID, Station, PWR, Rate, Lost, Packets and Probes stay blank. I use Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG but I'm confused because as I read through various sources, some say the patch needed for the chipset is not needed anymore and when I try to patch it regardless, I get errors. Yes I use this for educational purposes with my own WEP connection. Please help!

EDIT: Going through this [channel problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1793663.html) like mine (I think?) to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to generate traffic by performing an `ARP-request` packet injection, using `aireplay-ng`.

You'll need to use an authenticated client's `MAC Address` in the following commands in order to make them work, otherwise the injected packets are going to be ignored by the access point.

First perform a fake-authentication on the target access point: with `airodump-ng` running in the background, open another `Terminal` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run:

```
aireplay-ng -1 0 -e <SSID_name> -a <access_point_MAC_address> -h <associated_client_MAC_address> mon0
```

Then, open another `Terminal` and run:

```
aireplay-ng -3 -b <access_point_MAC_address> -h <associated_client_MAC_address> mon0
```

Comment: Awesome however I got "mon0 is on channel 7 but the AP uses channel 6" I'll use the code boxes for these posts next time I swear!

Comment: @Waypoint You have to set your interface to use the same channel of your access point, i.e. to start `airmon-ng` with `airmon-ng start mon0 6`

Comment: So I did your suggestion this time with the correct ch and got the Authentication success indicating I don't have mac filtering enabled. Now I'm trying `
sudo aireplay-ng -3 -b <AP MAC> -h MY:MA:CA:DD:RE:SS <interface>` but nothing happened, just "aireplay-ng --help for help" airodump-ng was running with no packets generating.

Comment: @Waypoint The command is `aireplay-ng -1 0 -e <SSID_name> -a <access_point_MAC_address> -h <associated_client_MAC_address> mon0`, and you'll need to use an authenticated `MAC address` in order to make it work, otherwise the access point will only generate useless `DeAuthentication` packets

Comment: @Waypoint Sorry I misread. `aireplay-ng -3 -b <access_point_MAC_address> -h <associated_client_MAC_address> mon0` is what you need, so you need to find the `MAC address` of a client associated to the access point in order to run this command as well

Comment: With that running, my packets of the my station is shooting up but the #Data rises slowly from the AP. Is that fine?

Comment: @Waypoint How slowly?

Comment: @Waypoint From [Aircrack-ng.com: simple_web_crack \[Aircrack-ng\]](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=simple_wep_crack): "The “#/s” should be a decent number. However, decent depends on a large variety of factors. A typical range is 300 to 400 data packets per second. It can as low as a 100/second and as high as a 500/second."

Comment: Pretty slow at around like 5 data ticks a minute. Got around 500 before I stopped. I'll stop here with extended comments to avoid rule breaking. Your info -greatly- helped me so I will take that and polish my skill and come back to help others here.

Comment: @Waypoint Glad that it helped, anyway I don't know what else to suggest you as long as injection is working, aside from trying to stay as close as possible to the access point, plus if the network is particularly active on his own (i.e. the authenticated client is sending/receiving lots of data) the `Data` packets transmitted should increase quite a bit accordingly